# Solving 2nd order nonlinear ode.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having this ode: $(a-b^2)z_{xx}-2b zz_x-\frac{1}{2}z^3+(c-rx)z=d+br$, where $z(x)$ is the unknown, and $a,b,r,c,d$ are all arbitrary constants. Can anybody give any hints?

Comment: Where did you encounter this equation? What are the initial / boundary conditions? Do you expect an exact solution, approximate or numerical solution?

Comment: There is no initial/ boundary conditions. I want an exact solution.

Comment: Try this resource, maybe your equation or some other one it can be reduced to is there: eqworld.ipmnet.ru/

Comment: Actually I have to solve a system of odes:  $bu_{xx}=-r-(rt+s+u)u_x-v_x,$ and $vu_x+uv_x+bv_{xx}+au_{xxx}=-(rt+s)v_x$ for $u$ and $v$.

Comment: Then you should edit the question